# Which is the most efficient / most elegant way to adapt large HTML code to variable number of PHP variables?

Tags: php, html, forms, performance

I have the following situation:

The USER can select from a list which columns to see in the UI table (columns that belong to different tables in the database (MySQL).

Let's assume this is a CRM software. So if the users selects the table *"Contacts"* he can also select data from other tables (Joined tables) like *"Companies"*, *"Industries"* etc.

**I have created a form that is supposed to contain every existing field** (in the  table and the joined tables) and a **jQuery script that will automatically check the related table** when a certain column within is checked (for a later Join)

So my form looks like this (general form, without variables):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    
    $('input[data-type="child"]').change(function()
    {
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(this).parents().eq(1).find('input[data-type="parent"]').prop('checked',true);
        }
        else 
        {
            if ($(this).not(':checked') && $(this).siblings(':checked').length == 0)
            {
                $(this).parents().find('input[data-type="parent"]').prop('checked', false);
            }  
        }  
    });
    
    $('div').find('input[data-type="parent"]').change(function()
    {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(parent).children().find('input[data-type="child"]').prop('checked', true)
        }
        else
        {
            $(parent).children().find('input[data-type="child"]').prop('checked', false)
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body
{
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.parent
{
    padding-top: 20px ;
}

.children
{
    padding-left:15px;
}

div.parent > label
{
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

div.children > label
{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

div.children > input
{
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <input data-type="parent" type="checkbox" value="p1" name="parent[]" value="p2" id="p1"><label for="p1">Table 1 <b><i>(will be hidden in UI)</i></b></label><br>
    <div class="children">
     <input data-type="child" type ="checkbox" name="child[]" value ="c1.1" id="c1.1"><label for="c1.1">Column 1.1</label><br>
      <input data-type="child" type ="checkbox" name="child[]" value ="c1.2" id="c1.2"><label for="c1.2">Column 1.2</label><br>
     <input data-type="child" type ="checkbox" name="child[]" value ="c1.3" id="c1.3"><label for="c1.3">Column 1.3</label><br>
     <input data-type="child" type ="checkbox" name="child[]" value ="c1.4" id="c1.4"><label for="c1.4">Column 1.4</label><br>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
    <input data-type="parent" type="checkbox" value="p2" name="parent[]" value="p1" id="p2"><label for="p2">Table 2 <b><i>(will be hidden in UI)</i></b></label><br>
    <div class="children">
     <input data-type="child" type ="checkbox" name="child[]" value ="c2.1" id="c2.1"><label for="c2.1">Column 2.1</label><br>
     <input data-type="child" type ="checkbox" name="child[]" value ="c2.2" id="c2.2"><label for="c2.2">Column 2.2</label><br>
     <input data-type="child" type ="checkbox" name="child[]" value ="c2.3" id="c2.3"><label for="c2.3">Column 2.3</label><br>
     <input data-type="child" type ="checkbox" name="child[]" value ="c2.4" id="c2.4"><label for="c2.4">Column 2.4</label><br>
    </div>
   </div>
```

**The problem is that each table will have a variable number of columns with different names. I have a PHP Script that will give me every relevant column of a table** (except of course the primary key and foreign key). So for each of these columns I have to add something like:

```
<input data-type="child" type ="checkbox" name="child[]" value ="column_name" id="column_name"><label for="column_name">Column name</label><br>
```

**Using echo for that whole HTML (and besides that, for the HTML for the parents and divs) is the only way of doing it? Or is there any other "cleaner" way of adapting large HTML code to PHP?**

Thanks.

Comment: You have Blade, Twig, Mustache, Smarty, Volt... all template engines.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely echoing is the worst way. Use a template engine, check out Twig:http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create the same form from PHP only. For eg:

```
 <?php

    function create contactTable($data) {

      foreach( $data as $coumnName ) {

        $checkbox = '<input data-type="child" type ="checkbox" name="child[]" value ='p1.".coumnName."' id='p1.".coumnName."'><label for="column_name">Column name</label>';

        return $checkbox;

      }

   }
 ?>
```

This helps you to maintain and debugging HTML easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel like using an outside engine, echo will work. To make this process faster, I would recommend writing a PHP function for each type of html element that you will need to build repeatedly. In psuedo code, you might want your php to look like this

```
$html = ""
For each table {
    $html .= openParent(); //to build your opening tag for the parent div and initial input element.
    $html .= openChildren() //creates the opening tag for your div with class children
        for each child {
            $html .= constructChild($valueToInsert, $tableIndex, $valIndex); //this will build a child input and insert the value you provided to the right places
        }
    $html .= closeParent(); //close the parent div tag
}

echo $html; //do whatever other behavior you need here, special char escaping etc.
```

I hope this makes sense. By breaking down your HTML into reusable function templates, you can increase readability and reduce filesize. This is a method I've used before for situations like this and I think it works quite well. I obviously did not flesh out my example very much as you will need to adapt it to your use case.

Edit: Here is what the constructChild function might look like

```
function constructChild($val, $tIndex, $cIndex)
{
$indexString = "c$tIndex.$cIndex";
    $returnString = "<input data-type='child' type ='checkbox' name='child[]' value ='$indexString' id='$indexString'><label for='$indexString'>$val</label><br>"
}
```